# Copy protobuf field to another protobuf in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

We have the following protobuf definition

```
message SubMessage {
  optional string var_1 = 1;

  repeated string var_2 = 2;
}

message MainMessage {
  repeated Foo1 foo_1 = 1;

  repeated Foo2 foo_2 = 2;

  optional SubMessage foo_3 = 6;
}
```

When trying to merge this subproto as part of the main proto

```
 proto::MainMessage main_message_proto;
 proto::SubMessage submessage_proto;

 ...

 main_message_proto.MergeFrom(submessage_proto);
```

The following error occurs:

`Tried to merge messages of different types`

What's the correct function to merge the information of the submessage as a field of the main message?

Comment: What does "merge" mean here? The two protos appear completely unrelated, not having anything at all in common. What exactly do you expect to happen as a result of that `MergeFrom` call? Say, where do you imagine the value of `submessage_proto.var_1()` would end up in `main_message_proto`?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it now. Was a typo in mocking the example

Comment: `main_message_proto.mutable_foo_3()->MergeFrom(submessage_proto)`

Comment: If you wish to format it as an answer I will accept it. Out of curiosity, how is that different from `main_message_proto.mutable_foo_3() = submessage_proto`?

Comment: `main_message_proto.mutable_foo_3() = submessage_proto` won't compile. I assume you mean `*main_message_proto.mutable_foo_3() = submessage_proto`. The two are equivalent if `foo_3` field is currently empty. If it already has values, then `MergeFrom` will, well, merge new values with existing ones. In this example, it will keep existing `foo_3.var_1` if `submessage_proto.var_1` is not set; and it will append `submessage_proto.var_2` to the end of `foo_3.var_2` . On the other hand, assignment will completely overwrite the original values, making `foo_3` and `submessage_proto` equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MergeFrom` merges two messages of the same type.  For example, if you had one `MainMessage` with its `foo_1` field set and another with its `foo_2` field set, you could merge them together and the result would be a message with both the `foo_1` and `foo_2` fields set.

But that's not what you have here.  You have a `MainMessage` and want to merge its `SubMessage` field with another `SubMessage`.  To do that you need to call `MergeMessage` on `foo_3`:

```
main_message_proto.mutable_foo_3()->MergeFrom(submessage_proto);
```

---

If `foo_3` is currently empty, then there's no need to use `MergeFrom`.  Simple assignment will do in that case:

```
*main_message_proto.mutable_foo_3() = submessage_proto;
```